# How to setup ubuntu for remote ssh access?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, remote

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop computer at home. I'd like to configure it so that I can `ssh` into it remotely. How would I go about this? Or this functionality already enabled?

Comment: By default it is not enabled. You need to `sudo apt install openssh-server`. But I sense you want to connect from some place in the internet (not from your local network), e.g. from office? Please clarify what you mean by _"remotely"_.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to ssh into my Ubuntu rig from beyond my local network. I used to ssh into a linux server from my macbook for a systems programming class, and I'd like to do likewise for my home machine.

Comment: Then things tend to get complicated. You either need a static public IP (from your internet provider) or some dynamic DNS (dyndns) service that maps the public IP you get from your provider whenever you go online to a fixed _name_. Furthermore, you need to configure your router to allow incoming connections from the internet via port 22 (ssh) and forward them to your local machine.

Comment: Thank you - I'll get to configuring that right away :)